# Updating Table Value when it is scrolled

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I need to display data in a cell, when the table gets loaded and when it is scrolled. I get data into the table rows the very first time the app is run, but when I scroll the table,  the table does not update all values. It shows only the last fetched value from the service.

My Service request format is :

```
http://vapp.sites.net/......userId=967730&rowsPerPage=10&nextCursorMark=1
```

**Note** - when i call service, the NextCursorMark is increased at response, which i m passing to next service call at scroll time.When nextCursorMark is nil i have to stop scrolling the table because there s no more new response data.

Response :

```
{
 MESSAGE: "Success",
 STATUS_CODE: 200,
 REQUEST: [ ],
 RESPONSE: {
 OrderList: [..<items>..],
 nextCursorMark: "2",
 totalOrderCount: 45
 }
 }
```

when the table gets loaded for the first time `nextCursorMark` value is `1` and on each scroll the value will be increased based on `totalOrderCount`. How can I manage the table view datasource when it is scrolled and the service is called, on each scroll?

My code below:

**1 - when loading the Table**

```
#pragma mark - UITableViewDataSource Methods

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)theTableView
{
return self.arrOrderList.count;
}

 - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)theTableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
 {
OrderList * objOrderList = (OrderList *)[self.arrOrderList objectAtIndex:section];
return objOrderList.orderDetailsList.count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)theTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"OrderDetailsListCell";
OrderDetailsListCell * cell = (OrderDetailsListCell *)[theTableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[OrderDetailsListCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
 }

[cell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone];
OrderList * objOrderList = (OrderList *)[self.arrOrderList objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
OrderDetailsList * objOrderDetailsList = (OrderDetailsList *)[objOrderList.orderDetailsList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
[cell loadDataWithOrderDetailList:objOrderDetailsList];
return cell;
 }



- (void) ServiceCallForOrderHistoryWithCurrentPageMark:(NSString *)page
{
if(![[VCSpinnerView sharedInstance] isSpinnerAddedToTheView:self.view])
    [[VCSpinnerView sharedInstance] showInView:self.view];

__block __weak VCMyOrderViewController* blockMyOrderListView = self;

[[VCModelManager sharedInstance] getMyOrderDetail:[[VCConfiguration sharedConfig] getLoggedInUserId] andPageNumber:page completionBlock:^(id result, NSError *error)
 {
        if (!error)
            {
                blockMyOrderListView.orderHistoryDataObject = (OrderHistoryBaseClass *)result;
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                [blockMyOrderListView setDataSourceMyOrders:blockMyOrderListView.orderHistoryDataObject.rESPONSE];});
            }
        else
            {
                NSLog(@"\nError->%@",[error debugDescription]);
            }
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [[VCSpinnerView sharedInstance] removeSpinnerView];
     });
  }];
}

- (void)setDataSourceMyOrders:(OrderRESPONSE *)response
{
self.orderHistoryDataObject.rESPONSE = response;

[self setPageMark:self.orderHistoryDataObject.rESPONSE.nextCursorMark];
[self setPageCount:[self.orderHistoryDataObject.rESPONSE.totalOrderCount integerValue]];
self.arrOrderList = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:self.orderHistoryDataObject.rESPONSE.orderList];

TrackOrderView *trackOrderView = [[TrackOrderView alloc] init];
[trackOrderView setDelegate:self];
[self.tblMyOrder setTableHeaderView:trackOrderView];
[self.tblMyOrder reloadData];
}
```

**2 -  when scrolling the Table**

```
- (void) scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
 {
   if (self.arrOrderList.count < self.pageCount)
     {
      [self ServiceCallForOrderHistoryWithCurrentPageMark:self.pageMark];
     }
  }
```

Comment: What's your `setDataSourceMyOrders `? Did u perform `reloadData` in main thread? it wont work if its in different thread, Did u set breakpoint in your function call in `scrollViewDidScroll ` and see if it call to it?

Comment: @Tj3n  i have updated code for setDataSourceMyOrders please have a look. I had set breakpoint and it is called

Comment: did it still call to your `setDataSourceMyOrders ` the 2nd time and the data u get is correct? or everything fine just your tableView not get updated?

Comment: @Tj3n it called on every time when i do scroll my table view does not get load based on scroll view

Comment: Where do you increase your nextCursorMark? I can't see, and in order to call your service with **nextCursorMark=2** you have to increase it previously. Am I wrong?

Comment: on each scroll the value of nextCursor mark is read and passed to service call.@nigelman

Comment: Its weird, your code seems pretty correct to me...did u tried to print the `arrOrderList` each times and see if u really did get the new data? it might be your new `arrOrderList ` is same as the old `arrOrderList ` so your `tableView` did not get any new data....Its really just the matter of your data source now since i saw u already call reload in main thread

Comment: @Tj3n arrOrderList.count depends on nextCursorMark value and i do pass nextCursorMark to service when i scrol and i do get the data. the thing is this i m missing some logic when i do scroll.

Comment: but you are calling for (service)&nextCursorMark=1, and your result has nextCursorMark = 1. And then, you set '[self setPageMark:self.orderHistoryDataObject.rESPONSE.nextCursorMark];' and you set THE SAME cursormark. And later you call your service using nextCursorMark = 1 again

Comment: @nigelman maybe the `nextCursorMark ` is already included in the response so its not he increase it himself...

Comment: I know. That's why I ask you: "Where do you increase the nextCursorMark"?

Comment: @tj3n i have updated my question as note please have a look  yes u r  right next cursor is increased on each response

Comment: So the array u received on the 2nd times is new and more value than the first time? since i saw u create new `arrOrderList ` everytime you call to the API....ur numbers of data is not increase at all but it replaced but not added, if its paged base...then it should be adding more

Comment: @Tj3n it is adding more if i pass nextCursorMark 1 then i will get few value for ex 10 if i pass next cursor mark i will get more count of 1 & 2 like this if i pass next cursor mark 5 then values will more . all it depends on total order count. as we can see total order count is 45 so it means i can scroll upto nextCursorMark 5 and when next cursorMark becomes nil i have to stop scrolling. hope u got me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to:

1. Have a mutable array to store the full list
2. Have variable to store the next URL (or next cursor mark)
3. In viewDidLoad, set the mutable array to an empty array, and the URL to the initial URL
4. Still in viewDidLoad, call your method to load more data
5. This method should append the data received to your mutable array, update the URL with the next URL to call (or nil if there's no more data)
6. The method should call `beginUpdates`, then `insertRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:` and then `endUpdates`
7. In scrollViewDidScroll, check the scroll offset against the size of the table and the visible size, and if you're near the end, call the method to load more data.
8. Of course, the method that loads additional data should exit right away when the URL to load is nil

Comment: i have set all points expect 7 and  8. how would you relate it to my code . please update via code.

Comment: The code you have shown in your question doesn't append the received data to the current list (item #5), but replaces it. It also doesn't call `beginUpdates`, `insertRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:` or `endUpdates` (#6). If you have made those changes, please update the code in your question.

Comment: For item #7, you'll need to use the tableView's `contentOffset.y`, `contentSize.height` and `frame.size.height` or `bounds.size.height`.

Comment: Item #8 is trivial. If there's nothing more to load, return.